# Google Cache and multi lingual domain names

Tags: caching, multilingual, google-search-console

I've developed a site which is available via two top level domain names. Both the language on the site is Dutch, one for the Dutch visitors and one for the Belgian visitors.

The .be version of the was recently "launched". Under the hood it's the same site ofcourse and we're using a meta tag to prevent getting penalized for duplicate content. ([Google's support page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en))

So; there's this page: www.domain.nl|be/vakantie/oostenrijk/tirol/
And depending on the TLD this is the implemented meta tag:

```
// Dutch site visitors
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl-NL" href="http://www.bergenmeer.nl/vakantie/oostenrijk/"/>
// Belgium site visitors
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl-BE" href="http://www.bergenmeer.be/vakantie/oostenrijk/"/>
```

The Belgian version is live since about 6 weeks. Both sites are equiped with a sitemap listing the URLs for that domain. But we're seeing the following in Google Cache.

*The live version of this page (see URL, phone number on the top right.*
[image: The live version of this page (see URL, phone number on the top right]

*The cached version of this page (see URL, phone number on the top right.*
[image: The cached version of this page (see URL, phone number on the top right]

When you load this page (despite some performance issues, we're looking into that) and you inspect the network traffic you'll see the page opens with a HTTP 200 response. No redirects whatsoever. Why is Google not showing the Belgian version of the page?

Thanks for the time you take to share your thoughts.

Ben

Answer (score 2):

For .be you could have

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.bergenmeer.be/vakantie/oostenrijk/"/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl-NL" href="http://www.bergenmeer.nl/vakantie/oostenrijk/"/>
```

and for .nl you could have

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.bergenmeer.nl/vakantie/oostenrijk/"/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="nl-BE" href="http://www.bergenmeer.be/vakantie/oostenrijk/"/>
```

Giving Google a hint at what you want prioritised and therefore to make it into the cache as it appears to only be using the alternate.

Comment: I'll give that a try. Thanks for your reply, +1. If it's the solution I'll give you the bounty as well!

Comment: I've given you the bounty anyway since you're the only one who reacted. Still have to try your solution though.

Comment: hey, @Ben, did you manage to make it work with this solution?

Comment: No. Are you facing the same issue? Any thoughts?